# AndroidStartActivity() Crashes

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

So heres a bsic run through of my code

Heres MainActivity.java:

```
package com.ngn;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button button;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Context context = this;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.helpbutton);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent ("com.ngn.HELP"); MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }

        });

}

}
```

And here is my help.java

```
package com.ngn;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.*;


public class Help extends Activity
{

private WebView webView;
@Override 
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
// superoncreate now
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.helpmenu);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/main.html");
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
            }

});;}}
```

every time i click the help button when compiled it freezes i use AIDE With Premium for android

Comment: Please format your code better. Any logcat errors?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add your LogCat output (the stack trace you get). Also please post your Manifest file content and finally try to use the auto formatter of your IDE to improve the code for better readability.

Answer (score 4):

in `Help` you have to call `setContentView` before trying to retrieve `R.id.helpmenu`

Comment: Do You realise how stupid you made me feel lol thanks a lot man that really helped :-)

Comment: Also you really shouldn't do I/O operations in your UIThread... And select the answer as correct ;)